# How i can add function to event on selected text in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Is any method to add event on text selection for div? I now that with Jquery possible add event to *input* and *textarea* .selected(), but i need to make same thing with *div* element.

For select manipulation i using [Range](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/DocumentationHome).

Is any method to do this with Jquery or JavaScript or with Range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a jQuery plugin for text selecting event:

http://plugins.jquery.com/node/7411